# replace odd and even occurence with html javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace ` ticks with html code in a string.

```
var str = "this `code` and `here`"
```

my expected output

"this code and here"

What i am trying to do is below
.

1. get the positions with ticks in a string
2. replace those ticks with span html based on odd and even occurence.

not sure, i couldnt get expected and my browser gets hang. and
when i debug it. i see there is no index  for string to replace.

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
}

var pos = [];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === "`") {
        pos.push(i);
    }
}


            if (pos.length > 1) {
                for (var j = pos.length; j > 0; j--) {
                    var index = pos[j];
                    var spanHtml = '';

                    if (j % 2 == 0) {
                        spanHtml = "<span class='code'>"
                    } else {
                        spanHtml = "</span>";
                    }

                    str = str.replaceAt(index, spanHtml);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is expected result `"this <span class='code'>code</span> and <span class='code'>here</span>"`?

Comment: You can use `String.prototype.replace()` , see post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp`

```
/(`\w+`)/g
```

`String.prototype.slice()` with parameters `1, -1` to slice string within backtick

```
`
```

characters

```js
var str = "this `code` and `here`";

var res = str.replace(/(`\w+`)/g, function(match) {
  return "<span class='code'>" + match.slice(1, -1) + "</span>"
});

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", res);
```

```css
.code {
  background: turquoise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. scope of var i is wider then you think, so pos.push(i) will have them all same at the end
2. replaceAt appends incorrect ending
3. replaceAt shifts rest of the string invalidating positions you found

I believe you wanted something along these lines:

```
var str = "this `code` and `here`"

String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+1);
}

var pos = [];
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === "`") {
        var index = i;
        var spanHtml = '';
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            spanHtml = "<span class='code'>"
        } else {
            spanHtml = "</span>";
        }
        count++;
        str = str.replaceAt(index, spanHtml);
        i+= spanHtml.length -1; // correct position to account for the replacement
    }
}

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript replace method.

```
var str = "this `code` and `here`";

var newStr = str.replace("`", "");
```